# .NET Globalization: Set Culture/UICulture on a Page or a Thread? What's the difference?

Tags: .net, globalization, culture, currentuiculture

Question title is basically the entire question. In ASP.NET you can set the Culture/UICulture properties of a page by overriding the InitializeCulture method, or you can set the properties of the current thread.

What are the differences? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both? What situations would you use each option?

Comment: There you go: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches ultimately set the properties on the current thread.

The biggest difference is that the `Page` methods support automatic language detection - they can determine the language from the request (if you set the value to "auto", optionally with a default). By contrast, the `Thread` methods require a specific culture instance.

For a web application, I'd just use the `Page` methods, because they provide additional options and save me the (admittedly trivial) trouble of constructing a `CultureInfo` instance myself.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense. One quick followup though.. how is the language detected from the request?

Comment: It accesses it through [HttpRequest.UserLanguages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx), which parses the request's HTTP headers. (I *think* the `Accept-Language` header, maybe `Content-Language`.)