# Difference between CurrentCulture, InvariantCulture, CurrentUICulture and InstalledUICulture

Tags: .net, internationalization, globalization

What is the difference between `CurrentCulture`, `InvariantCulture`, `CurrentUICulture` and `InstalledUICulture` from `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUiCulture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of) and [.NET Globalization: Set Culture/UICulture on a Page or a Thread? What's the difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933345/net-globalization-set-culture-uiculture-on-a-page-or-a-thread-whats-the-diffe)

Comment: No duplicate but similar and helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231386/when-should-i-specify-currentculture-or-invariantculture-and-when-should-i-leave

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I would try to give a bit more insightful answer than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of/329041#329041).

**CurrentCulture** should be used for formatting. That is, Numbers, Currencies, Percentages, Dates and Times should *always* be formatted with this culture before *displaying them to user*. Few examples here:

```
const string CURRENCY_FORMAT = "c";
const string PERCENTAGE_FORMAT = "p";

DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow; // all dates should be kept in UTC internally
// convert time to local and format appropriately for end user
dateLabel.Text = now.ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

float someFloat = 12.3456f;
// yields 12,3456 for pl-PL Culture
floatLabel.Text = someFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
// yields 12,35 zł for pl-PL Culture - rounding takes place!
currencyLabel.Text = someFloat.ToString(CURRENCY_FORMAT, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
// yields 1234,56% for pl-PL Culture - 1.0f is 100%
percentageLabel.Text = someFloat.ToString(PERCENTAGE_FORMAT, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

One important thing to note is that you should never use `float` nor `double` for storing currency related info in the first place (`decimal` is the right choice).
The other common use case for `CurrentCulture` is Locale-aware parsing. Your application should *always* allow users to provide input in their regional format:

```
float parsedFloat;
if (float.TryParse(inputBox.Text, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out parsedFloat))
{
    MessageBox.Show(parsedFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), "Success at last!");
}
```

Please note that I always provide `IFormatProvider` parameter, although it is implied and assumed to be `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. The reason for it is, I want to communicate with fellow developers: this is something that will be displayed to end users. This is one of the reasons why FxCop treats omitting this parameter as error.

---

**InvariantCulture** on the other hand should be used to convert reliably one of the classes mentioned above to its textual representation. So if you want to for example transmit `DateTime`, `float`, `double` or similar object via network, store it to database or some kind of text file (including XML), you should *always* use `InvariantCulture`:

```
float someFloat = 1234.56f;
// yields 1234.56
string internalFloat = someFloat.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
// yields something like 04/16/2011 19:02:46
string internalDateAndTime = now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

A thing to note here is that date/time format offered by `InvariantCulture` is actually exactly the same as en-US. Although it is reliable, it is not exactly correct. What really should be used is [ISO8601 Interchangeable Date & Time Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). For some reason Microsoft does not even provide such pattern (the closest ones are Sortable pattern - "s" and Universal pattern - "u" which only resembles ISO8601 format), you would need to create your own like this:

```
const string iso8601Pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
string iso8601Formatted = now.ToString(iso8601Pattern);
```

Quite important side note: `IFormatProvider` is actually **required** here as omitting this parameter may result in serious errors. I once had to fix a defect on French OS. The code was like this:

```
float dbVersion = // some kind of logic that took float from database
string versionString = dbVersion.ToString(); // culture-aware formatting used
Version ver = new Version(versionString); // exception thrown here
```

The reason was very simple: float formatted on French OS (with French regional formatting) was formatted to something like 10,5 and `Version` class requires Culture-invariant input.

---

**CurrentUICulture** is responsible for loading appropriate translatable resources for your application. That is, it should be use for displaying correct text messages, colors and images.
In Asp.Net application if you want to for some reason implement CSS Localization Mechanism (ability to override CSS definitions per language), `CurrentUICulture` is good way to go (provided that you actually read this property from web browser).
Likewise if you want to implement language switching mechanism, `CurrentUICulture` is the one that should be overridden.

---

**InstalledUICulture** is wired to Default OS UI Locale. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.installeduiculture.aspx) says:

> This property is the equivalent of GetSystemDefaultUILanguage in the Windows API.

To actually understand what this property is, we need to dig into some theory. There are different Windows product lines:

- single language (i.e. English, French, German, Japanese, etc.)
- MUI (that is Multilingual User Interface - English base OS and Language Packs)

For single language product lines, InstalledUICulture will always return Operating System language, whereas for MUI it should always return English (United States) aka en-US. Is it useful? I don't know, I never needed such an information. And personally I haven't seen program that took advantage of this property.

Comment: You don't need to use the above ISO8601 pattern string (anymore?). This should also work: `myDate.ToString("o")`. The `o` or `O` format string will convert the date/time into ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/329041/390989):

> CurrentCulture is the .NET representation of the default user locale
>   of the system. This controls default number and date formatting and
>   the like.
>
> CurrentUICulture refers to the default user interface language, a
>   setting introduced in Windows 2000. This is primarily regarding the UI
>   localization/translation part of your app.
>
> Whatever regional options the system is configured to have will be the
>   "Current" values in your .NET app.
>
> Often times they are both the same. But on my system they would be
>   different: I prefer my numbers and dates in the German format, so the
>   CurrentCulture would be German, but I also prefer all my applications
>   in English, so the CurrentUICulture would be English.