# Cannot get current server culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, globalization, cultureinfo

I am working on multi Lingual application in c# asp.net MVC, in which server, client or both may have different languages other than English. My development machine has English as default language, and using language bar in windows, I have set my current language to French (belgium), my client end browser language is Dutch(belgium). For every request I used to change Thread Current Culture to Dutch(client end browser language) using globalization techniques as follows.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie userCookie = Request.Cookies["Culture"];
    string cultureCode = "en-US";
    if (userCookie != null)
    {
        cultureCode = userCookie.Value;
    }
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

I wanted to find OS current culture, therefore, I used

```
CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture
```

to find OS current culture, which should be French(Belgium) FR-BE, but every time it is returning me en-US English(united states). I already know that problem is with windows, it always returns default windows culture instead of current Culture as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060446/difference-between-currentculture-invariantculture-currentuiculture-and-instal). I wanted to know, is there any way to find current OS culture which is French(Belgium) FR-BE on my server.

Comment: I don't see much value in figuring "default server's culture"... Consider specifying one explicitly in Web.config `<globalization uiculture...` instead (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Side note: Unless you means something different than "using language bar in windows" have zero impact on current culture, it only impact what language will be used in input fields..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might want to check:

```
public static CultureInfo CurrentCulture { get; set; }
public static CultureInfo CurrentUICulture { get; set; }
```

This should contain the default OS culture when your application starts.

Comment: sorry, not default. but you must grab or set them at startup