# How to add formatProvider parameter to NLog.LogEventInfo.Create method?

Tags: nlog, iformatprovider

I have following NLog 2.0 code to log exceptions:

```
Dim theEvent = NLog.LogEventInfo.Create(NLog.LogLevel.Error, loggerName, message, ex)
```

After upgrading to NLog 4.1 I see following warning:

> Function Create(logLevel As LogLevel, loggerName As String, message As String, exception As Exception) As LogEventInfo' is obsolete: 'use Create(LogLevel logLevel, string loggerName, Exception exception, **IFormatProvider formatProvider**, string message)'

... it asks me to add **IFormatProvider formatProvider** as parameter. What should I add there?

```
Dim theEvent = NLog.LogEventInfo.Create(NLog.LogLevel.Error, loggerName, ex, ???, message)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely use `null`, one from the `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` members (a good guide can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5689410/928651)) or create your own custom format provider depending on your needs.

The current implementation (as of v.4.1.2 on [GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog)) will simply use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` if the `FormatProvider` property is `null`.