# decimal.Parse not working as expected with localisation settings

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, windows-server-2012-r2

My application suddenly started failing to convert a string value of format `"18.000"` to a decimal or int with the error

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

When trying either

```
decimal.Parse(stringValue);
int.Parse(stringValue);
```

Even though a couple of days earlier this was working fine. It also worked on my local machine but not on the publishing server.

It turns out I could resolve this by passing in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` like this:

```
decimal.Parse(aod.PnPQuantity, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But when I check the server's localisation settings, it definitely uses a `.` as a decimal seperator:

[image]

My question is, how is this possible? Is there some other setting I need to check, and is this something that could have changed on its own or has someone been messing with my settings?

Will passing in `InvariantCulture` as I have prevent this from happening in the future, or do I need to take further precautions?

Comment: Where is the string coming from?

Comment: @ZoharPeled The string is sent through as an element in a larger soap message, which I recieve, process and insert into an ms-access db

Comment: This might help you understand what is needed/recommended in number formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060446/difference-between-currentculture-invariantculture-currentuiculture-and-instal

Comment: What I means is are you sure the string should always be well-formatted, or is it coming from a source you don't control such as a 3rd party of user input. Because if it's the second option, you should prefer `TryParse` over `Parse`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The string comes from a 3rd party, and yes I should be using `TryParse`, but that is not what is causing the issue as I have verified several inputs myself and the issue still occurs

Comment: Ok, so yes, to answer your question, sending `InvariantCulture` to the `Parse` method will cause it to try and parse the input string according to the `InvariantCulture` rules, not the local settings of the OS the application is running on.

Comment: @ZoharPeled But the question is, why does `Parse` (without `InvariantCulture`) fail to do the conversion when the OS settings looks correct

Comment: If I would have known that, I would have posted an answer, not a comment...

Comment: @ZoharPeled You said "to answer your question" - which question were you answering exactly?

Comment: The last one: "Will passing in InvariantCulture as I have prevent this from happening in the future, or do I need to take further precautions?" It's not my fault your post contains multiple questions :-)